# How do I the add vocabulary name or the ID to the <body> CSS classes?

Tags: 8, theming, taxonomy-terms

For theming purpose, I would like to add in body class the vocabulary name (or ID) of the current taxonomy.
I know how to add a class based on the taxonomy term ID.

For example, I have the following vocabulary (*Color*).

- red (term id = 1)
- green (term id = 2)
- yellow (term id = 3)

I know how to get `<body class="term-id-1">`. I would like to get `<body class="vocabulary-id-1">` or `<body class="vocabulary-name-color">`.

I've tried the following code.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Works
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
    $variables['term_id'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term');
  }
  // doesn't work
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_vocabulary.canonical') {
    $variables['vocabulary_id'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_vocabulary');
  }
}
```

As said in the comments, it doesn't work, and I am not able to use the vocabulary name, or its ID as CSS class to add to the `<body>` tag.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vocabulary id is not a route parameter, unless you have a route to view/edit a vocabulary, but these are all admin routes. So you need to get the information from the term:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
    // load the term entity and get the data from there
    $term = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term');
    $variables['term_id'] = $term->id();
    $variables['vocabulary_id'] = $term->bundle();
  }
}
```

[bundle()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Abundle/8.4.x) returns the vocabulary of the term. This is the same as a content type of a node. Or a block type of a custom block. All are fieldable bundles of entities.

So if you use `bundle()` on a node you'll get for example the machine name `article`.

Comment: Thanks, it works very well. I understand your explanation.

Comment: +1. I would also point out that in Drupal 8 the ID is the machine name, so vocabulary ID and vocabulary name are the same thing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I've added an explanation what bundle() does.

Comment: I've put the above code in my .theme file and then went to my `views-view.html.twig` file and tried to print `{{ term_id }}` and `{{ vocabulary_id }}` and both return as null. I'm trying to add the term as a class to the surrounding `div` so that I can style the different taxonomy term pages. Any ideas as to why I'm not getting any value returned?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me to get the tid into the body class for a taxonomy term page, with the addition of this code: $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'term-' . $term->id();